# Unforunatly, App Name has stopped. Newbie here

Tags: android, xml, eclipse, android-manifest

When I am trying to run my android application.The emulator says Unfortunately Appname has stopped. I'm a newbie and I am following a tutorial in a book please help.How can I fix this this error?

**This the manifest**

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<manifest xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    package="com.example.hellowworld"
    android:versionCode="1"
    android:versionName="1.0" >

  <uses-sdk
      android:minSdkVersion="18"
      android:targetSdkVersion="18" />

  <application
      android:allowBackup="true"
      android:icon="@drawable/ic_launcher"
      android:label="@string/app_name"
      android:theme="@style/AppTheme" >
    <activity
        android:name=".MainActivity"
        android:label="@string/app_name" >
        <intent-filter>
            <action android:name="android.intent.action.MAIN" />

            <category android:name="android.intent.category.LAUNCHER" />
        </intent-filter>
    </activity>
</application>
```

**logcat error**

```
10-07 03:30:52.800: I/Process(781): Sending signal. PID: 781 SIG: 9
10-07 03:36:21.560: D/AndroidRuntime(825): Shutting down VM
10-07 03:36:21.570: W/dalvikvm(825): threadid=1: thread exiting with uncaught exception (group=0xb3aded70)
10-07 03:36:21.580: E/AndroidRuntime(825): FATAL EXCEPTION: main
10-07 03:36:21.580: E/AndroidRuntime(825): Process: com.example.hellowworld, PID: 825
10-07 03:36:21.580: E/AndroidRuntime(825): java.lang.RuntimeException: Unable to instantiate activity ComponentInfo{com.example.hellowworld/com.example.hellowworld}: java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: Didn't find class "com.example.hellowworld" on path: DexPathList[[zip file "/data/app/com.example.hellowworld-1.apk"],nativeLibraryDirectories=[/data/app-lib/com.example.hellowworld-1, /system/lib]]
10-07 03:36:21.580: E/AndroidRuntime(825):  at android.app.ActivityThread.performLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2123)
10-07 03:36:21.580: E/AndroidRuntime(825):  at android.app.ActivityThread.handleLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2258)
10-07 03:36:21.580: E/AndroidRuntime(825):  at android.app.ActivityThread.access$800(ActivityThread.java:138)
10-07 03:36:21.580: E/AndroidRuntime(825):  at android.app.ActivityThread$H.handleMessage(ActivityThread.java:1209)
10-07 03:36:21.580: E/AndroidRuntime(825):  at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:102)
10-07 03:36:21.580: E/AndroidRuntime(825):  at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:136)
10-07 03:36:21.580: E/AndroidRuntime(825):  at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:5026)
10-07 03:36:21.580: E/AndroidRuntime(825):  at java.lang.reflect.Method.invokeNative(Native Method)
10-07 03:36:21.580: E/AndroidRuntime(825):  at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:515)
10-07 03:36:21.580: E/AndroidRuntime(825):  at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:777)
10-07 03:36:21.580: E/AndroidRuntime(825):  at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:602)
10-07 03:36:21.580: E/AndroidRuntime(825):  at dalvik.system.NativeStart.main(Native Method)
10-07 03:36:21.580: E/AndroidRuntime(825): Caused by: java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: Didn't find class "com.example.hellowworld" on path: DexPathList[[zip file "/data/app/com.example.hellowworld-1.apk"],nativeLibraryDirectories=[/data/app-lib/com.example.hellowworld-1, /system/lib]]
10-07 03:36:21.580: E/AndroidRuntime(825):  at dalvik.system.BaseDexClassLoader.findClass(BaseDexClassLoader.java:56)
10-07 03:36:21.580: E/AndroidRuntime(825):  at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(ClassLoader.java:497)
10-07 03:36:21.580: E/AndroidRuntime(825):  at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(ClassLoader.java:457)
10-07 03:36:21.580: E/AndroidRuntime(825):  at android.app.Instrumentation.newActivity(Instrumentation.java:1061)
10-07 03:36:21.580: E/AndroidRuntime(825):  at android.app.ActivityThread.performLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2114)
10-07 03:36:21.580: E/AndroidRuntime(825):  ... 11 more
10-07 03:41:21.720: I/Process(825): Sending signal. PID: 825 SIG: 9
10-07 03:47:53.940: D/AndroidRuntime(877): Shutting down VM
```

**Xml**

```
<RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:paddingBottom="@dimen/activity_vertical_margin"
    android:paddingLeft="@dimen/activity_horizontal_margin"
    android:paddingRight="@dimen/activity_horizontal_margin"
    android:paddingTop="@dimen/activity_vertical_margin"
    tools:context="com.example.hellowworld.MainActivity" >
</RelativeLayout/>

    <TextView
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:text="@string/hello_world" />
```

**Java**

```
package com.example.hellowworld;

import android.app.Activity;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.view.Menu;
import android.view.MenuItem;

public class MainActivity extends Activity {

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);
    }

    @Override
    public boolean onCreateOptionsMenu(Menu menu) {

        getMenuInflater().inflate(R.menu.main, menu);
        return true;
    }

    @Override
    public boolean onOptionsItemSelected(MenuItem item) {

        int id = item.getItemId();
        if (id == R.id.action_settings) {
            return true;
        }
        return super.onOptionsItemSelected(item);
    }
}
```

Comment: The stacktrace and your manifest are not really telling the same thing. Are you sure you've copied the correct version of both. Also your XML layout as posted has syntax problems, indicating it's not the version you were running. Anyway, I believe the stacktrace is the most reliable and it says `Didn't find class "com.example.hellowworld"` when launching an activity which would indicate you had your package name for your activity full name in your manifest.

Comment: can you pl confirm you package name is hellowworld ... its two "w" inside. most probably it will be helloworld

Answer (score 0, accepted):

**In Manifest try using full-Path name**

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<manifest xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    package="com.example.hellowworld"
    android:versionCode="1"
    android:versionName="1.0" >

  <uses-sdk
      android:minSdkVersion="18"
      android:targetSdkVersion="18" />

  <application
      android:allowBackup="true"
      android:icon="@drawable/ic_launcher"
      android:label="@string/app_name"
      android:theme="@style/AppTheme" >
    <activity
        android:name="com.example.hellowworld.MainActivity"
        android:label="@string/app_name" >
        <intent-filter>
            <action android:name="android.intent.action.MAIN" />

            <category android:name="android.intent.category.LAUNCHER" />
        </intent-filter>
    </activity>
</application>
```

**Clean the project and run again**

Answer (score 0):

In Eclipse's do following steps

Step 1. Project → Clean

Step 2. Build and Run your Application.